# Best practices for request response handling in express application

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, design-patterns

I have a REST API built on express (and using typescript) with following structure

> - app.ts
> - routes
> - controllers
> - models

**Question** : Which is the best place to handle/build the request/response? will that be in routes or controllers ?

I am divided between 2 approaches in mind

1 - Using routes for only mapping the corresponding method in controller, have request and response handling inside the controller class file

2 - Using the routes for handling request and building response based on response from the corresponding  method in controller. In this way I can re-use controller methods from different routes when needed.

Any suggestions on which is the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

A scalable approach will be to forward the request to a controller method from the routes and let the controller to take care of the response. Handling the response in the routes can bloat it as your application grows.

Now, the question of reusability here can be solved by adding another layer to your application called services. Services will be pure classes where your business logic will live and it can be re-used within controllers.

Hope this helps.